# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string [Makefile]

Tags: android, linux, makefile

Not able to find the problem:

make PLATFORM=android

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/debian/Downloads/nonemaioq3'
CC code/client/cl_cgame.c
/prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: 4: /prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make[2]: *** [build/release-android-arm/client/cl_cgame.o] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/debian/Downloads/nonemaioq3'
make[1]: *** [targets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/debian/Downloads/nonemaioq3'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

and this is the Makefile I got:

http://pastebin.com/QYZYVvTn

I don't find any problem there :S Help please.

Comment: I don't know if the problem is on the Makefile, or on the arm-linux-androideabi-gcc :S... anyone know?

Comment: <edit> Try running `make -d` and it should tell you what `CC` is doing.  That might help.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `file /prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`?  That would say how the OS sees it.  Just for grins, what is line 4 of `code/client/cl_cgame.c`?

Comment: Well, the cl_cgame.c is something like this

/*
ETC
ETC
ETC
ETC
ETC
ETC
*/

and the output of androideabi-gcc I don't know cuz I can't execute it: bash: ./arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
CC code/client/cl_cgame.c
```

starts the compiler (C Compiler or `CC`).  The error message is after the CC and doesn't start with `make`, so it relates to the compiler, not the Makefile.

```
/prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: 4: /prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

`gcc` is the GNU C compiler.  The error is in the file `/prog/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`, on line 4.

In view of your comment, "arm-linux" means that version of GCC is meant to run on ARM processors.  If you are running this on a PC, you want a gcc with "x86" or "x64" in place of "arm."  That would be a cross-compiling situation; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098978/android-cross-compile-ndk-toolchain) for links on how to set that up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

It's a binary file.. that's the strange.